# Solving $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$ in ${\Bbb Z}_{11}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

The question is from a multiple choice problem:

> How many elements $x$ in the field ${\Bbb Z}_{11}$ satisfy the equation $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$?
>   A.1 B.2 C.3 D.4 E.5

I know that one may need *Fermat's little theorem* to solve $x^{10}(x^2-1)\equiv 2\pmod{11}$.

How should I go on?

Comment: I frankly don't understand your question. How do you show that the equation $x^{12}-x^{10}=2$ is equivalent to $x^{10}(x^2-1)=2$, when you are looking for solutions in the real numbers? The same principles apply.

Comment: Or is the problem that you don't know that working in ${\bf Z}_{11}$ is the same thing as working mod 11?

Comment: @Gerry: Yes, you are right. I don't understand why working in ${\bf Z}_{11}$ is the same thing as working mod 11.

Comment: @Jack: If you post a separate question, I (or others) can give you the answer of why "working in $\mathbb{Z}_m$" is essentially the same as "working with congruences modulo $m$". But the comment boxes are too narrow to contain it.

Comment: @Arturo: Thanks for your patience. I have added the question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45750/9464).

Comment: @Jack: I apologize for coming thru a bit harsh with the first comment. In retrospect I should have recognized what your problem was. Glad that it has now been identified and remedied. This will quickly become a deep-rooted second nature. So much of second nature that you no longer see the difference!

Comment: @Arturo "But the comment boxes are too narrow to contain it." I take that as alluding to the other Fermat's theorem :-)

Comment: @Srivatsan: Only unconsciously.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fermat's Little Theorem tells you that $x^{11}\equiv x\pmod{11}$, and that if $x$ is not congruent to $0$ modulo $11$, then $x^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$. Since $x=0$ is certainly not a solution, we may restrict our attention to nonzero $x$; so $x^{12} = x^{10}x^2 \equiv x^2\pmod{11}$, and $x^{10}\equiv 1 \pmod{11}$.

Then this becomes $x^2-1\equiv 2\pmod{11}$, or $x^2\equiv 3\pmod{11}$. There are either two or no solutions, and since $0$ is not an option, the answer is B.

The fact that $x^{12}-x^{10}\equiv x^{10}(x^2-1)\pmod{11}$ is simply because $11$ divides $(x^{12}-x^{10}) - x^{10}(x^2-1)$, no matter what (integer) $x$ is.

**Added.** I don't understand your added question. $a$ is a solution to $x^{10}(x^2-1)\equiv 2\pmod{11}$ if and only if it is a solution to $x^{12}-x^{10}\equiv 2 \pmod{11}$, simply because 
$$x^{12}-x^{10} = x^{10}(x^2-1)$$
for any integer (for any complex number, even!). Things that are equal remain equal modulo any equivalence relation (such as congruences), because equivalence relations are always reflexive.

**Apropos of Nothing.** You can determine if there are solutions or not (if you didn't have the answers in front of you) either by simply testing the numbers modulo $11$, or by using [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity). Both $3$ and $11$ are congruent to $3$ modulo $4$; since $11\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ is not a square modulo $3$, then $3$ *is* a square modulo $11$.

Comment: It's my ignorance that I didn't understand why working in ${\bf Z}_{11}$ is the same thing as working mod 11. I understood the definition of congruence superficially. "$a=b$ in the field ${\bf Z}_{m}$" is the same thing as "$a\equiv b\pmod{m}$". Right? Now I see.

Comment: @Jack: Except that $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is a field if and only if $m$ is a prime. The elements of the **ring** $\mathbb{Z}_m$ are equivalence classes of integers, where the equivalence relation is "congruent modulo $m$, so indeed, saying "$a=b$ in the *ring* $\mathbb{Z}_m$" is in fact the exact same thing as saying $a\equiv b \pmod{m}$, if you use an integer $a$ and $b$ to represent the congruence class modulo $m$.