# A lattice of integer congruence classes

Tags: modular-arithmetic, lattice-orders

Let the notation $[a]_n$ stand for $\{a + kn \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  If $n = 0$, this is $\{a\}$; otherwise, this is $\{b \mid b \equiv a \pmod{n}\}$.

We can define a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)) $L$ whose elements are of the form $[a]_n$.  The top element is $\top = [0]_1 = \mathbb{Z}$.  We can also add a bottom element $\bot = \varnothing$.

We can compute joins as follows: given $x = [a]_m$ and $y = [b]_n$, let $g = \gcd(m, n, |a - b|)$.  Then $x \vee y = [a]_g = [b]_g$.  (And as usual, $x \vee \bot = \bot \vee x = x$.)

I am interested in doing some [data flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis) with this lattice as the abstract domain, so it's useful to perform arithmetic with elements of this lattice.  E.g. for addition, I'd like an operation $x + y = z$ on lattices that is compatible with integer addition, i.e. $r \in x, s \in y \implies (r + s) \in z$.  One possible definition is:
$$
[a]_m + [b]_n = [a + b]_{\gcd(m, n)}
$$
and I think that's as precise as possible.

I'd also to define multiplication of lattice elements.  So far I've come up with
$$
[a]_m [b]_n = [ab]_0 + [0]_{an} + [0]_{bm} + [0]_{mn}.
$$
Is there a better (more precise and/or simpler) definition of multiplication over $L$?  It's been a while since I did discrete math but most of what I remember only applies to the $m = n$ case.  The only tool I know for handling different moduli is Chinese remaindering but I don't see how it would help here.

And more generally: is there an established name for $L$?  Or books/papers that discuss it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I don't think that $[a]_m [b]_n = [ab]_0 + [0]_{an} + [0]_{bm} + [0]_{mn}$ holds. Take $a=2,m=3,b=1,n=4$ for example. LHS does not have $1$ as an element while RHS has. In other words, there are no integers $s,t$ such that $(2+3s)(1+4t)=2+8t+3s+12st=1$ while there are integers $x,y,z$ such that $2+8x+3y+12z=1$. I think this is where the difficulty lies. I got only partial results.

Comment: @mathlove Yes I think it's unavoidable that multiplication overapproximates, but that's okay.  I only need $[a]_m [b]_n \supseteq \{(a + j m) (b + k n) \mid j, k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

> I only need $[a]_m[b]_n\supseteq\{(a+jm)(b+kn)\mid j,k\in\mathbb Z\}$

Then, how about the following?

$$[a]_m [b]_n=[ab]_{\gcd(an,bm,mn)}$$

which might be simpler.

---

Another way is

$$[a]_m [b]_n=[ab]_{\gcd(m,n)}$$

If $\gcd\bigg(\frac{an}{\gcd(m,n)},\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}\bigg)=1$ or $\gcd\bigg(\frac{bm}{\gcd(m,n)},\frac{mn}{\gcd(m,n)}\bigg)=1$, then we have
$$[a]_m[b]_n=\{(a+jm)(b+kn)\mid j,k\in\mathbb Z\}$$

**Examples** :

- $[1]_3[5]_6=\{(1+3j)(5+6k)\mid j,k\in\mathbb Z\}$
- $[5]_6[7]_8\supset  \{(5+6j)(7+8k)\mid j,k\in\mathbb Z\}$

Comment: $[a b]_{\gcd(m, n)}$ is quite a bit less precise, e.g. that would give $[3]_0 [0]_1 = [0]_1$, while $[0]_3$ would be better.  But your suggestion above that is good, thanks!

Comment: @Tavian Barnes : Ah, you are right, and you are welcome.

Comment: @Tavian Barnes : "Or books/papers that discuss it?" I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/45775/78967) which may be related with what you are talking about.